# Hikari connection pool set idle connection but have limit connection in oracle Db

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using "hikari" for making connection Pool and setting min idle connection 10. 
I am also setting profile with max 3 connection in oracle Db.

what is happening to connections? when creating idle connection, there is no exception but when software wants more connection, it is giving exception or waiting.

Following is the configuration for Hikari -

```
 HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
 config.setMinimumIdle(10);
....
```

Comment: Did you try the HikariCP [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hikari-cp) ?

Comment: It seems like you are setting the minimum to a number larger than the maximum. Also, according to Hikari, the default settings are quite good for most use cases, unless absolutely necessary, try not to change too much, as pool optimization is quite hard to get right.